# Cubic Bezier from sample points

Tags: bezier, curve-fitting

The sample points is taken from a flying machine in a fix sample rate (e,g 1s=25 frame), it contains the x,y,z position.

The requirement is to import the point lists and edit the curve, then export it to a new point lists. 
I want to use the **Cubic Bezier curve** to display the points, the problem is :

1. The flying path is arbitrary, can it always be drawn in Bezier curve?
2. How to confirm the **vertex** and **control** points?

The reason of vertex and control point is for editing, i want to drag the control point to modify the curve.

Am new for this field, any suggestion or sample code is appreciated. :)

Comment: I think this question is related and could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312834/how-to-interpolate-n-points-that-do-not-describe-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cubic Bezier spline won't fit to an arbitrary digitized curve. If Cubic Bezier spline approximate your curve with unacceptable square error, there are two options:

1. Split original curve into segments (for example, where curve bends) and then fit segments with Cubic Bezier splines. There is a description of [an algorithm for automatically fitting digitized curves](http://iut-arles.univ-provence.fr/web/romain-raffin/sites/romain-raffin/IMG/pdf/PSchndeider_An_Algorithm_for_automatically_fitting_digitized_curves.pdf)
2. Use higher order Bezier splines than cubic, which can fit any continuous smooth curve.
   This will result in iterative process to find Bezier spline of minimum order fitting the curve with an acceptable error.

Comment: Thanks divanov, the link : an algorithm for automatically fitting digitized curves help me a lot. 
But it's 2D point algorithm, only x, y, no z, how to apply it to 3D point? Do u have any idea? :)

Comment: There is not much difference between 2D, 3D cubic Bezier splines. The same formulae apply.

Comment: oh, cool , i have used this algorithm to 3D points and it works well, thank you very much @divanov.

Comment: An additional question: This algorithm can fit the curve well when decrease the error and increase the iterations, but the points is too much, do u know any better ways to reduce the control points?

Comment: Algorithm seems to deal with cubic Bezier splines only, thus, results only in four control points. Fitting depends on the data. If your data samples are something like [white noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise), then Bezier curve simply won't fit. The data has to be smooth.